# c++ объект статической инициализации map<T1,T2>

Tags: c++, c++17

Не получается правильно сконструировать класс для статической инициализации `map<T1,T2>`, ругается на синтаксис и просит точку с запятой там где не надо.
В общем запутался в синтаксисе..

**Header.h**

```
  typedef std::map<long, std::wstring> HresMap;
  HresMap HresTest;

template <typename T, typename U>
class InitStaticMap2
{
private:
    std::map<T, U> _map;

public:
    InitStaticMap2::InitStaticMap2(std::map<T, U>& map)
    {
        _map = map;
        return *this;
    }
    InitStaticMap2<T, U>& operator() (const T& key, const U& val) const
    {
        _map[key] = val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator std::map<T, U>()
    {
        return _map;
    }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
  #include "Header.h"
  InitStaticMap2<long, std::wstring>(HresTest)
       (123L, L"aaa")
       (124L, L"baa")
       (125L, L"aba");
```

вот оригинальный класс, в таком виде собирается и работает, VS2017

**Header.h**

```
namespace ErrorList
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    class InitStaticMap
    {
    private:
        std::map<T, U> _map;

    public:
        InitStaticMap::InitStaticMap(const T& key, const U& val)
        {
            _map[key] = val;
        }
        InitStaticMap<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U& val)
        {
            _map[key] = val;
            return *this;
        }
        operator std::map<T, U>()
        {
            return _map;
        }
    };

    typedef std::map<long, std::wstring> HresMap;

    HresMap HresultTest = InitStaticMap<long, std::wstring>
       (123L, L"aaa")
       (124L, L"baa")
       (125L, L"aba");
}
```

Comment: В глобальной области видимости нельзя просто так вызывать функции. Собственно и статической инициализации тут будет недостаточно. А `HresMap HresTest;` вызовет ошибки линковки.

Comment: Да, но если все тоже самое унести в хеадер и немного изменить класс, чтоб он работал на создаваемый перед ним объект, то все работает. `HresMap HresTest = InitStaticMap1<long, std::wstring>(..)(..)(..);`

Comment: В таком варианте это уже будет инициализацией переменной, а не вызовом функции. Но статической инициализации будет по-прежнему недостаточно и ошибки линковки никуда не денутся.

Comment: @VTT, странно, ошибки у меня не возникает при сборке, сейчас приведу оригинальный класс из которого я этот мастерю. Собираю VS2017, на gcc не пробовал пока, руки не дошли.

Answer (score 3):

Если хитрая инициализация глобального объекта, то можно сделать так:

```
std::map<int, std::string> globalMap 
    = [] {
        std::map<int, std::string> result;
        result[1] = "1";
        result[2] = "2";
        return result;
    }();
```

Если инициализация простая, то

```
std::map<int, std::string> globalMap = {{1, "1"}, {2, "2"}};
```

Если очень хочется использовать InitStaticMap2, то

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class InitStaticMap2
{
private:
    std::map<T, U> _map;

public:
    InitStaticMap2<T, U>& operator() (const T& key, const U& val)
    {
        _map[key] = val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator std::map<T, U>()
    {
        return _map;
    }
};

std::map<int, std::string> mp = InitStaticMap2<int, std::string>()(1, "2")(2, "2");
```

Comment: отлично, но очень громоздко, с описанием каждой пары.

Comment: Опять же, статической инициализации тут будет недостаточно.